# In what ways did the points made by the writer in the introduction contradict/contradicts her conclusion?

Tags: grammatical-number, verb-agreement, reference

> In what ways did the points made by the writer in the introduction
>   contradicts her conclusion?

(In the question listed above, shouldn't "contradicts" be written as "contradict" - since we are referring to the "points" made by the writer?)

Comment: Yes; it should be *contradict* because *points* is plural.

Comment: Elliott, please elaborate - thank you. (Grammarly accepted "contradict" as correct) - OK, I understand (simplify) - unless, the focus is "points"?

Comment: @Chris Simplify; Does the introduction contradict her conclusion?

Answer (score 3):

Simplifying the sentence...

> In what ways did the points made by the writer in the introduction contradicts her conclusion?

Take out adjectival phrases:

> In what ways did the points [made by the writer] [in the introduction] contradicts her conclusion?
>   In what ways did the points contradicts her conclusion?

Simplify "In what ways"; simplify "her conclusion":

> How did the points contradicts it?

*Contradicts* must be wrong, as it should be an infinitive form.

Comment: No, even if it were *point*, it would be *contradict*.

Comment: @PeterShor Ooh. Yes. It's an infinitive with an auxiliary verb.